# AJAX JQuery: Why do query parameters disappear in server side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express

I wrote the following client-side code:

```
$("button").click(function() { 
      $.ajax({
         url: 'http://bank-example.com:3000/login',
         data: JSON.stringify({
            username: $('#username').val(),
            password: $('#password').val()
         }),
         error: function() {
            console.log("error");
            alert('FAIL');
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(data) {
            alert('OK');
            console.log("success");
         },
         contentType: "application/json",
         Accept: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         type: 'POST'
      });
});
```

When the AJAX request reaches the server, and I try to access query params by:

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res) {
   console.log(req.query.password);
   console.log(req.query.username);
}
```

I get 'undefined'.

When I look in the networks tab, I see this screenshot: 
[image]

It looks that these params are sent, but I don't succeed to access them.

Comment: because... you didn't pass that data in the `query`? it's in the body.

Comment: What do your controller/params/model look like?

Comment: To get POST data with node/express, you should use `req.body`, not `req.query`

Comment: req.body is also undefined

Comment: See the last example on this page: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-get-url-and-post-parameters

Comment: specifically, you need `var bodyParser = require('body-parser');app.use(bodyParser.json());` on the server

Comment: @CrazySynthax The request are not going in params. Its in Request body. If you want to send the values in query params. Your URL should look something like this ' www.api.com?username: xxx , password: xxx'

Comment: If you are using multer, the body sets to empty if you don't set the `enctype='multipart/form-data'` in your form, to avoid this you can use body-parser for the most of your requests and multer only for those that handle files.

Comment: @JohnHascall, you're right. The solution is to take care of the server according to the link you published.